# How do I access each word in Assembly?

Tags: arrays, assembly, cpu-word, mips64, edumips64

Given:

```
.data
arr: .word 2,5,1,3,4
len: .word 5
sum: .word 0
```

How would I access each word in "arr" such as 2, 3 and 4?

Eventually, what I would like to do is find a sum of all of the values in "arr", but I'm having difficulty iterating through "arr".

Thank you for your time!

Additional Info:

1. I'm using eduMIPS64

Comment: You may want to give more details on the context of this question. CPU, assembler, etc would be helpful.

Comment: @JoshuaBerry presumably it would be x86 assembly. Not many other types floating around that'd be used in the mainstream.

Comment: @Liam my guess is that ARM and embedded PIC systems outnumber x86.

Comment: @JoshuaBerry Sorry, I'm completely new to this. I'm using eduMIPS64...I'm not quite sure what other information would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First load the address of the array into a register, then you can access the items with a constant offset. (Your assembler might support constructs such as `lw $t0, arr+12` as convenience shorthand for this. See your manual.) For iteration, either increment the address register, or add another register containing the offset. Be sure to account for item sizes. Folling example is for 32 bit mips, adjust as necessary for 64 bit:

```
.data
arr: .word 2,5,1,3,4
len: .word 5
sum: .word 0

.text
.globl main
main:
    la $t0, arr
    lw $t1, 12($t0)     # load arr[3] using byte offset
    li $t1, 3           # index
    sll $t1, $t1, 2     # multiply by item size
    addu $t1, $t1, $t0  # add base address
    lw $t1, ($t1)       # load arr[3]

# iteration type 1
# for(i=len, ptr=arr; i != 0; i -= 1, ptr += 1)
# ... use *ptr ...
    la $t0, arr
    lw $t1, len         # load length
loop1:
    lw $t2, ($t0)       # load item
    # process item here
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    # add item size to pointer
    addi $t1, $t1, -1   # decrement counter
    bne $t1, $0, loop1  # if counter != 0, repeat

# iteration type 2
# for(i=0, i != len; i += 1)
# ... use arr[i] ...
    la $t0, arr
    lw $t1, len         # load length
    li $t2, 0           # index
loop2:
    sll $t3, $t2, 2     # multiply by item size
    addu $t3, $t3, $t0  # add base address
    lw $t3, ($t3)       # load item
    # process item here
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    # increment index
    bne $t2, $t1, loop2 # if index != len, repeat
```

(note these sample loops do not handle zero length array, add check if necessary)

Comment: Wow, this is comprehensive. Thank you for taking the time to explain this!

Comment: I'm having an issue that while I increment the index, the values for "arr" are stored in addresses 0, 8, 10, 18, 20, 28, 30, etc. Why is the spacing by 8 and 2 there? Why isn't it simply incremented by the size of a word?

Comment: Are your numbers in hex by any chance? ;)

Comment: T_T, that would make sense, wouldn't it. Thanks for bearing with me!