# How can I use a for loop for an Assembly MIPS instruction?

Tags: for-loop, assembly, mips

So I have been busy with assembly lately, and I am stuck with using a for loop. I have searched through the internet, but I don't understand any of it. I have to loop `SLL  $1,$1,4 # sll operation` for X amount of times. How can I do this?

```
#generated assembly code for SIMPL
@include "Mips.wasm"
.data   MyRegisters:    REGISTERS
0:  WORD    zero    0      
1:  WORD    temp    0      
2:  WORD     0      
3:  WORD     0      
4:  WORD     0      
5:  WORD     0      
6:  WORD     0      
7:  WORD     0      
8:  WORD     0      
9:  WORD     0      
10: WORD     0      
29: WORD    sp      0      
31: WORD    ra     
.data   MyMemory:   DATAMEM
50: WORD stack  # start of stack
0:  WORD    a       0      
1:  WORD    b       0      
2:  WORD    result  0      
.code   MyCode: MIPS,MyMemory
    J       INIT   
L1: # main
    LUI     $1     , 1          # storing numeric into reg
    ORI     $1     , $1     , 0   
    SW      $1     , a      , $0        # assignment of var
    # expr;
    LUI     $1     , 0          # storing numeric into reg
    ORI     $1     , $1     , 1000      
    SW      $1     , b      , $0        # assignment of var
    # expr;
    LW      $1     , b      , $0        # storing var into reg
    LW      $2     , b      , $0        # storing var into reg
    SLL     $1     , $1     , 4         # sll operation
    SW      $1     , result , $0        # assignment of var
    # expr;
    LUI     $1     , 0          # storing numeric into reg
    ORI     $1     , $1     , 1      
    #return int value   # stack ret value
    JR      $31     # return
INIT:   # Start of our program
    J       L1      # jump to the main code
END:
```

Comment: I assume you know conditional branches? Write some pseudocode or draw a flowchart.

Comment: Oh, it sounded like I have some assembly knowledge. I actually am a beginner. I just don't know how to implement the code for it.

Comment: You can see an [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13655852/547981) (see _iteration type 2_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no loops in assembler, that's a C (or similar language) concept.

Instead, there are conditional branch instructions used to jump based on a test.

```
 li    $t0, 10
 li    $t1, 0
 loop:
 addi  $t1, $t1, 1
 bne   $t1, $t0, loop
```

This would roughly correspond to a C "for" of:

```
for( int n = 0; n < 10; ++n ) {}
```

Where other code MIPS code doing actual work (that which would appear in the brackets in C) would be situated between the loop: label and the addi instruction.

Comment: `addi  $t1, $t1, 1` <-- shouldn't that be `addi  $t1, $t1, -1` ?

Comment: $t1 starts at zero, and increments until 10, so it should be addition not subtraction. If it were -1 instead, the loop would run until the integer wraps around, iterating billions of times on a 32 bit device. If you're thinking in terms of the link sample above, that example starts the counter at 3, and loops from there TO zero, non inclusive.